# Vue text input mask

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I looking for **VueJS 2** text `input` mask, I didn't find anything useful after research.

I would like to mask user input, e.g.

```
192.169.0.1/32
```

I found vue library like [v-mask](https://github.com/probil/v-mask), but it is only for npm, when I do not using it.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Inputmask library and jQuery

One of the solution is [inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask) library in combination with jQuery to manipulate with DOM elements.
As you mention that you don't use `npm`, you need to include script in right order:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="inputmask.js"></script>
<script src="inputmask.extensions.js"></script>
```

Working example: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jfjmhxaz/1/)